# Decoding relationship between two numbers?

Tags: find, numbers, relationship, calculator

Is there any way (or calculator) to determine the relationship between two numbers.

Comment: I'm guessing the two numbers are related in a way that is very complicated to guess, otherwise there would be no point in using this system if anyone could easily fake the numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not necessarily be any relationship between the two. One might be a sequence (1, 2, 3, 4) and the other might be random.

Do you have any other information you can share that would indicate there must be a relationship between the two?

Answer (score 1):

1. From the UID, take the first 2 digits (80) and multiply by 4, then add the 3rd digit (3).
2. Take digits 3 and 4 (30) and add 6.
3. Take digits 5 and 6 (98) and subtract 8.
4. Take last 2 digits (25) subtract 5, then flip the digits and append all numbers.

This could be the decode algorithm, and 99.9999%, It's not, you will never no.

Anyway, I was just showing that the decoding could be anything. **Use your imagination.**

Answer (score 0):

Relations to numbers can be anything from hamming distances to custom hash results. Very hard to find out perfectly, you would have to find more numbers.